# XML - view not being inherited?

Tags: xml, inheritance, view, odoo

I have defined this view:

```
    <record id="product_normal_variant_form_view_inherit1" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.product.form.inherit1</field>
        <field name="model">product.product</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product_variant_multi.product_normal_variant_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="weight_net" position="after">
                <field name="width_net" attrs="{'readonly':[('type','=','service')]}"/>                                     
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>    

</data>
```

When I install module to update view, it goes without any errors. But view does not change. And looking in a list of views for product.product, this one does not appear. I thought maybe system didn't see this view, so I just entered some wrong syntax in view, but then of course I got error.
So system sees this view, but for some reason does not register it. And the stranger thing is, I used this view before and it worked. But now it does not and I am out of ideas what could be wrong..
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was wrong. Well stupid me:). I added another view with same id, so it would always override that view, because in configuration it was after that view I had problem. So I just needed to change id for one of the views.

Comment: you should be use `position=attributes`. I dont think so your xml code will be work.

Comment: the old "copy&paste and then miss to edit the id" mistake ;-)

Comment: @CZoellner yes, you are right, i delete my answer and field name is also different. Thnaks

Comment: @CZoellner yeah, that was exactly what happened :)